# Connect to RDS via EC2 using phpMyAdmin

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, phpmyadmin, amazon-rds

I am trying to connect to an RDS instance using phpMyAdmin running on an EC2 instance.
The error I am getting is: `Cannot log in to the MySQL server`.

I have scoured the other posts on this topic but none of the solutions have helped.

My set-up is:

CentOS Linux release 7.7.1908 (Core)

phpMyAdmin-4.4.15.10-4

5.5.64-MariaDB

PHP 5.4.16

Here is what I have tried so far:
**I can connect to the RDS instance via the MySQL Client CLI on the EC2 Instance**
My `/etc/phpMyAdmin/config.inc.php` contains the following:

```
$i++;
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = 'myrdshere.eu-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['port'] = '3306';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type'] = 'tcp';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = 'mysql'; # I have tried with mysqli as well
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['compress'] = TRUE;
```

I have tried hard coding the username and password into the `config.inc.php` file.
My RDS instance is configured to accept all traffic from the EC2 instance (confirmed as **I can access RDS via the CLI**)

I have amended `/usr/share/phpMyAdmin/libraries/config.default.php` to contain the server details.

I have rebooted the RDS instance.

More details on my set-up:
I have my domain pointing to the EC2 instance so I am accessing phpMyAdmin via `http://mydomain/phpmyadmin` using Google Chrome.

My public IP has got all traffic allowed in and out of the EC2 instance.

I am at a complete loss of what else to try here. Does anyone have any ideas?

Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found my issue, I had to run the following: setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect=1